# Django test client does not log in

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am attempting to log in the test client using its built in login function. I am trying to unit test views and need to log in to test some of them. I have been trying to do this for too long and need help.
A few notes:

create_user() does create a valid user, It has been used in other locations.

From what I have seen about client.login() it returns a boolean, when I ran my tests the failure was "False is not True", so this appears to be correct.

The only way I have successfully logged in is by calling client.post("/my/login/url", {username and password in dict.})
However, for some reason It does not stay logged in for all of my test cases which I find VERY strange.

```
def setUp(self):
    """
    Initializes the test client and logs it in.
    """
    self.user = create_user()
    self.logged_in = self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)

def test_valid(self):
    self.assertTrue(self.logged_in)
```

I have changed it to the following:

```
def setUp(self):
    """
    Initializes the test client and logs it in.
    """
    self.password = "password"
    self.user = create_user(password=self.password)
    self.logged_in = self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.password)
```

It still fails to log in.

create user is in class "Static" and has a user_count initialized as 0, the function is as follows:

```
def create_user(username=None, password=None, email=None, is_superuser=False):
    if username is None:
        username = "user%d" % Static.user_count
        while User.objects.filter(username=username).count() != 0:
            Static.user_count += 1
            username = "user%d" % Static.user_count
    if password is None:
        password = "password"
    if email is None:
        email="user%d@test.com" % Static.user_count

    Static.user_count += 1
    user = User.objects.create(username=username, password=password,   is_superuser=is_superuser)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot access the password directly. The `password` attribute is encrypted. (See [Password management in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/passwords/).)

For example, here sample output of password.

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username='asdf', email='asdf@example.com', password='xxxx')
>>> user.password
'sha1$166e7$4028738f0c0df0e7ec3cec06843c35d2b5a1aae8'
```

As you can see, `user.password` is not `xxxx` I given.

I'd modify `create_user` to accept optional password parameter. And pass a password both to `create_user`, and `client.login` as follow:

```
def setUp(self):
    """
    Initializes the test client and logs it in.
    """
    password = 'secret'
    self.user = create_user(password=password)
    self.logged_in = self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=password)
```

**UPDATE**

`create_user` should use [`User.objects.create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) instead of `User.objects.create`. And the created user object should be returned:

```
def create_user(username=None, password=None, email=None, is_superuser=False):
    if username is None:
        username = "user%d" % Static.user_count
        while User.objects.filter(username=username).count() != 0:
            Static.user_count += 1
            username = "user%d" % Static.user_count
    if password is None:
        password = "password"
    if email is None:
        email="user%d@test.com" % Static.user_count

    Static.user_count += 1
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
    #                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
    user.is_superuser = is_superuser
    user.save()
    return user # <---
```

Comment: So is there a way to get the password from user? or Would I just have to know the password?

Comment: @user2278110, As mentioned in the answer, password is encrypted (hashed), and cannot be decrypted. You should pass it to `create_user` (probably need modification to the `create_user`) and use that password instead of `self.user.password`.

Comment: @user2278110, Could you show the content of the `create_user` function?

Comment: It is now there but I am fairly certain the issue is not in create_user

Comment: @user2278110, Where is the return statement in `create_user`?

Comment: @user2278110, And if if `create_user` in the `Static` class, why don't you call it as `Static.create_user(..)`?

Comment: @user2278110, I updated the answer with `create_user`. Check it out.